# Relation between Left factoring a grammar and removing epsilon

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

Let's say I'd using below grammar for compiler

```
 S -> a | aB
```

if I perform left factoring on it, it would be like (e is epsilon)

```
 S -> aC
 C -> B | e
```

then I want to remove epsilon which ends up being like

```
 S -> a | aC
 C -> B
```

notice that it looks like I again need to perform left factoring, and doing so infinitely left factoring and removing epsilon back and forth. Am I doing something wrong ??

Is it require to remove both left factoring and epsilon on grammar for compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do either transformation, most of the time. In fact, for some grammars, left-factoring will create shift-reduce conflicts for LALR(1) parser generators.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you have to write epsilon after left factoring.

> S -> aC
> C -> B

This will be considered correct in most of the cases.